# A voltmeter reads $120$ volts. It is known that the voltmeter reading is $0.5\%$ too high. What should the correct reading be?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A voltmeter reads $120$ volts. It is known that the voltmeter reading is $0.5\%$ too high. What should the correct reading be?

I am majorly confused on this question. I did: $1.05\%=0.0105$
\begin{align*}
0.0105x & = 120\\
x & = 11428
\end{align*}

This is obviously wrong. How would I do it correctly? It would be great if you could give me a clear and simple explanation and show me why I should not divide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error is the factor used. You have 0.5% more than the assured amount, thus the factor of increase is $1+0.5/100=1.005$ - not $0.0105$. 
Now, calling the original amount  $x$, we know that $1.005x=120$, so by direct division, $x=120/1.005$.

Comment: This turns out to be 119V (3 s.f.). The exact number before rounding can be checked by multiplication with the factor of increase, which confirms the answer.

Comment: could you also go 100%+0.5% is 100.5% which equals 1.005?

Comment: Yes, that's a perfectly valid equivalent. Doing it that way might also help ensure the percentage is converted to a factor correctly, and to follow where each part of it comes from.

Answer (score 1):

Voltmeter reads - 120V

Error - 0.5%

1% of 120V -> 1.2V

0.5% of 120V -> 0.6V

Actual value ->case 1:  Measured - Error( Measured reading is higher than actual )

```
          -> 120 - 0.6

          -> 119.4 V
```

Comment: "It is known that the voltmeter reading ... is too high." The meter-reading-low case is not necessary. Nor is the answer you give for it the correct one in that case; you would have to add 0.5% to obtain what it should read, since a too-low reading must intuitively increase to match true value.